# Make a set of random Integers Scala

Tags: scala, random

Is there a way in Scala to have a set of Ints be random without duplicates?

For example, I have set of Ints currently set to zero by default; a,b,c,d,e. And I want to assign a random int to each one from 1-100 while never assigning the same number to any of the variables. Thanks.

Comment: How many ints do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I can see two ways how this can be done.

First is the simplest one. If the range (1-100) is small enough, you can just generate every value in this range, shuffle them and take first `m`:

```
import scala.util.Random

Random.shuffle(0 until 100 toList).take(4)
```

result:

```
res0: List[Int] = List(54, 11, 35, 15)
```

But if range is large, this won't be very efficient (as range must be materialized in the memory). So in the case when the number of picked values (`m`) is much smaller than the range (`n`), it's more efficient to generate random values until you pick one that wasn't used before.

Here is how:

```
import scala.util.Random

def distinctRandomMOutOfN(m:Int, n:Int):Set[Int] = {
  require(m <= n)
  Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(n)).scanLeft(Set[Int]()) {
    (accum, el) => accum + el
  }.dropWhile(_.size < m).head
}

distinctRandomMOutOfN(4, 100)
```

result:

```
res1: Set[Int] = Set(99, 28, 82, 87)
```

The downside of the second approach is that if `m` is close to `n` it takes average time close to `O(m²)` to compute.

---

**UPD**.

So if you want a general solution that will work efficiently in any case you may use hybrid variant. Use the first approach if `m` is at the same order of magnitude as `n` (i.e.  `m * 2 >= n`) and second variant otherwise. 
This implementation will use `O(m)` memory and will have an average running time of `O(m)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can be confident that there are no duplicates if you simply shuffle all the possible elements and then take what you need.

```
import scala.util.Random

Random.shuffle(1 to 100).take(5)  // res0: Vector(74, 82, 68, 24, 15)
```